# how to pass a viewmodel object from view to controller and then from controller to view in mvc3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In a quiz application I have a 'Question' domain object having a number of fields including question description and number of choices. I can load and view the first question as below but then on form submit I want to send this viewmodel and load the next question object without post back. I have seen few examples of ajax calls using jquery but I can't find any example where we can pass the whole object via ajax calls between controller and view

```
@model  BusinessModel.Question
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Survey";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Survey", "Tools", new { QuestionId = Model.QuestionId },    FormMethod.Post, new { onsubmit = "return getCheckedRadioButton();" }))
{
    <div id="QuestionContent">
        <h2>Welcome To Quiz</h2>

        <fieldset>
            <p>
                Question
                @Model.QuestionId of @ViewBag.QuestionCount:
            </p>
            <p>
                @Model.Description.
            </p>
            <ul style="list-style:none;">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Answers)
                {
                    <li> @Html.RadioButton("ChoiceList", item.score) @item.AnswerDesc</li>

                }
            </ul>

            <input type="submit" value="Next" id="submitButton" />
        </fieldset>

    </div>
}
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: why not use Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: Could you kindly give an example similar to my requirement using Ajax.BeginForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a JavaScript object which has same fields in `Question` class and pass it as a JSON object to controller on submit.

```
var question = {};
// fill the viewmodel object.

$.ajax(
{
    url: 'Tools/Survey/',
    data: JSON.stringify({question : question }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        // data contains next question and you can create the view accordingly
    },
    error: function () {
       // error
    }
});
```

In the `Controller` you can access the `Question` and return your next `Question` as a JSON like below;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Survey(Question  question )
{
    // get the next question
    return Json(new { question = nextQuestion }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Please refer following post for more information.

[Pass Complex JavaScript Object to MVC Controller](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2014/01/pass-complex-javascript-object-to-mvc.html)

It illustrates how we can pass complex javascript objects to MVC controller.

Thanks !